# Using IR thermometer for measuring component temperature

Tags: temperature, infrared, meter

I'm trying to measure the temperature of various steel components being heated using power frequency induction heater. The IR meter being used can be set for emmissivity  value of 0.1 to 1.0.
For the same type of material EN353, I'm not able to get the satisfactory   reading of temperature of different components keeping the emmissivity and
measuring distance same.
What other factors need to be considered- is it the mass / profile / surface
finish of various components, etc..
I'm comparing the reading of IR meter with a hand held calibrated K-type temp. indicator

Comment: Can you label or paint a spot on the component with something that has satisfactory emissivity?

Comment: Put black Tesa or similar matte black electrical tape on it or paint it with Tipp-ex and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

> What other factors need to be considered- is it the mass / profile / surface
>   finish of various components, etc..

Only surface finish and material as that's what's emitting the IR.

---

Some reading:

> Most **high-quality electrical tape** has an emissivity of 0.95. One must be careful, especially with mid wavelength cameras (3-5 μm), that the tape is opaque. Some vinyl tapes are thin enough to have some infrared transmittance, and are therefore unacceptable for use as high-emissivity coatings. Scotch™ Brand 88 black vinyl electrical tape has an emissivity of 0.96 in both the short wavelength (3-5 μm) and long wavelength (8-12 μm) regions, and is recommended.  Source: [FLIR](http://www.flir.com/science/blog/details/?ID=71556).

---

> If you are using a thermometer with a fixed, preset emissivity of 0.95, and need to measure a shiny object you can compensate by covering the surface to be measured with spray oil, flat black paint or **masking tape**. Measure the temperature of the taped or painted surface. That is the true temperature. Source: [Raytek](http://www.raytek.com/raytek/en-r0/ireducation/emissivity).

---

> For relatively low temperatures (up to 500°F), a piece of **masking tape**, with an emissivity of 0.95, can be measured. Then adjust the emissivity value to force the indicator to display the correct temperature of the material. Source: [Omega](http://www.omega.com/prodinfo/infraredthermometer.html).

---

Each of the above articles is probably worth a read.

Answer (score 0):

Emissivity not only depends on the material itself, also from the surface. For iron and steel, I find

```
electrolytic iron, high gloss polished: 0.05...0.06
forged iron, high gloss polished:              0.28
rusted iron                                    0.69
```

With lower values, the material starts to act as mirror, and the IR meter starts to see the thermal radiation from other stuff nearby.
If you put your IR meter into a tank made of polished iron, you'll be fine with a value of 0.28 or so, but if you aim it to smaller parts, you get wrong results.

It would be best to cover the parts with something of high emissivity. An easy solution is soot, directly from a yellow flame, which has an emissivity of >0.95.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the temperature that you are wanting to measure.

There are Infra-Red (IR) temperature sensors that use "2 color", or "Dual wavelength" process to reduce effects of emissivity differences. [See this article.](http://blog.williamsonir.com/the-difference-between-two-color-and-dual-wavelength-pyrometers)

Also, when steel (and other metals) are heated to higher temperatures, scaling (oxidization) of the surface occurs, which can cause errors in temperature readings using a single wavelength IR measuring device. In other words the emissivity changes as scale builds up on the surface of the heated object.

A 2 color (or dual wavelength) IR measurement system may provide you with correct temperature measurement.